# When Paul mentions baptism for the dead in 1 Corinthians 15:29, what is he talking about?

Tags: 1-corinthians, soteriology, death, resurrection, baptism

1 Corinthians 15:29

> Now if there is no resurrection, what will those do who are baptized for the dead? If the dead are not raised at all, why are people baptized for them?

The LDS Church uses this as a prooftext for their practice of being baptized on behalf of ancestors who died without being baptized.  This practice is rejected by every other form of Christianity I am aware of.

I'm looking for a Protestant, Catholic, or Orthodox interpretation of this verse.  Most of the commentaries I have consulted thus far say that we don't know what Paul was talking about.